# Linq expression for comparing two enum values

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm doing some expression building in my app, which is working most of the time.  But when I try to do comparative operations on an enum value, I hit trouble.  For example:

```
expr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(memberExpression, constExpression);
```

This works fine until `memberExpression` and `constExpression` are of type `MyEnum`; this throws a runtime error:

> The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 'MyNamespace.MyEnum' and 'MyNamespace.MyEnum'.

I could get around it some other place by converting the enum values to integers, but that seems wrong, somehow.  If I can do a comparative operation between `MyEnum` values in C#, then why doesn't the Expression builder allow it?

Comment: possibly because the comparative operator casts to integers?

Comment: "I could get around it some other place by converting the enum values to integers, but that seems wrong" => Why? enums are nothing more than "numbers with labels". Obviously when you want to *compare* such values, you compare the numbers.

Comment: @Jon, my point is exactly that; why should the `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` fail, if enums are just numbers with labels?

Comment: @Shaul: I imagine because when writing live code the compiler replaces the labels with the values automatically, while when you build an expression tree you are on full manual mode: what you write is what happens, no more and no less. So when compiling, `Foo.Bar < Foo.Baz` is translated into `2 < 3`, but with the expression tree you get two values of type `Foo` -- and that type does not define the less-than operator.

Comment: @Shaul: And of course if you have nonconstant expressions the compiler inserts the required casts (which may not be casts to `int`, enums can be backed by other types too) automatically, while again doing the same in terms of expressions would result in moderately complicated subtrees. If `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` worked that way, you would think you were adding a single node but behind the scenes you would be adding a whole bunch of stuff.

Comment: try casting the Enums to int

Comment: @Jon, you can post your comments as an answer here.  Meanwhile I asked the next stage of this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22380584/7850).

Comment: @Shaul: I just did, expanding a bit as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could get around it some other place by converting the enum values
>   to integers, but that seems wrong, somehow.

It shouldn't feel wrong. That's what the compiler itself does, after all -- it either substitutes enum values for their corresponding numeric values (when the enum values are known at compile time) or it generates code that performs the necessary casts at runtime. Note that these casts are not necessarily to `int` but rather to the backing type of the enum in question.

> If I can do a comparative operation between `MyEnum` values in C#, then
>   why doesn't the `Expression` builder allow it?

The expression tree you are building looks like it matches what happens in C# code, but in reality it doesn't -- precisely because of what the compiler does behind the scenes as mentioned above.

It is true there is no *technical* reason that `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` and friends cannot examine their arguments and generate the exact same expression tree that corresponds to what the compiler would do. For example, if you pass in two `ConstantExpression`s with `Type` equal to `MyEnum` the method could use reflection to determine the numeric values that correspond to its arguments and behave as if you had passed in constant expressions of that type instead of throwing. It could also handle the general case (non-constant subexpressions) as well.

However, doing so would mean that the WYSIWYG property of expression trees is lost: you would think that you are generating an expression tree X while in reality you would be generating a different expression tree Y.

That might be perfectly desirable -- and you can certainly write methods of your own that do this -- but it is probably not a good idea as the default behavior (in general the design of C# shuns the [DWIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) mentality), and/or would not justify the cost of development. Keep in mind that there are a great many places where the compiler does the heavy lifting out of sight so accommodating just a subset of these scenarios would be arbitrary, while accommodating all of them would probably be prohibitive. It would be interesting to see if the availability of [Roslyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) changes this evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually did not convert to integers.

```
private static void Example(string value, Type type, ParameterExpression pe, string propertyName)
{
    Expression whereValue = null;
    if (type.IsEnumOrNullableEnum())
    {
        whereValue = Expression.Constant(Enum.Parse(type, value));
    }
    Expression propExp = Expression.Property(pe, propertyName);
    Expression ruleExpression = Expression.Equal(propExp, whereValue);//results in: item.MyEnum = A
}
```